# Remix hydration error with i18n translation: "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML"

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, i18next, remix

**Title**:
Remix hydration error with i18n translation: "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML"

**Question**:

I am working on a Remix project and have integrated i18n translation. However, I am encountering several hydration errors when trying to render my content. The primary error message I'm seeing is "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML".

**Error Logs**:

```
[Error] Warning: An error occurred during hydration...
[Error] Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML...
[Error] Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match...
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object...
[Error] Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match...
[Error] Error: There was an error while hydrating...
```

Can anyone guide me on how to diagnose and fix these hydration issues with Remix and i18n translations?

**Code Snippet**:

```js
<Document lang={lang}>
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Layout>
            <Outlet />
        </Layout>
    </I18nextProvider>
</Document>
```

Comment: PS: the translations render correctly on the page, I'm concerned about the hydration errors in the console

Comment: Perhaps you could use [remix-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remix-i18next?activeTab=readme) which has specific instructions for hydration?

Comment: I have tried that library and I encountered the same issue

Comment: Have you fixed this problem? I'm facing the exact same situation on my end